# Qooxdoo, set appearance for required textfield

Tags: themes, qooxdoo, appearance

I want to add some specific style for required fields, but I wantto have only one appearance id. Something like states

```
MyAppareance: {
    style:function () {
        if (required) {
            // add some special styling
        }
    }
}
```

I can misuse states for this, which I would like to avoid.

I there a way to access instance of control that is being styled in appearance declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no convenient way to access widget being styled. so I use states to overcome this problem.